# Finding intersections of sets in R

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, intersection

I have the following data-frame, and want to return the index from this data-frame that corresponds to the vector [1 1 1 1 0 0 1]. Func. should return 5 in this case.

> 1: 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
>
> 2: 1 0 1 1 0 0 1
>
> 3:  2 0 1 1 0 0 1
>
> 4:  0 1 1 1 0 0 1
>
> 5:  1 1 1 1 0 0 1
>
> 6:  2 1 1 1 0 0 1
>
> 7:  0 0 2 1 0 0 1

What about if we have another data.frame consisting of

> 1:  0 0 2 1 0 0 1 == 7
>
> 2:  0 1 1 1 0 0 1 == 4
>
> 2:  2 0 1 1 0 0 1 == 3
>
> 4:  2 0 1 1 0 0 1 == 3
>
> 5:  2 1 1 1 0 0 1 == 6

I would like the function to return 7,4,3,3,6. I would like to accomplish this without using a loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second (and effectively the first question as well since you can add whatever rows you want to the data frame) question:

```
mydf$rownum <- 1:nrow(mydf)
merge(mydf.sub, mydf, sort=F)[[8]]
```

Produces:

```
[1] 7 4 3 3 6
```

Or without the `[[8]]`:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 rownum
1  0  0  2  1  0  0  1      7
2  0  1  1  1  0  0  1      4
3  2  0  1  1  0  0  1      3
4  2  0  1  1  0  0  1      3
5  2  1  1  1  0  0  1      6
```

If you want the answer to the first question baked in:

```
merge(rbind(mydf.sub, c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)), mydf, sort=F)
```

Produces:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 rownum
1  0  0  2  1  0  0  1      7
2  0  1  1  1  0  0  1      4
3  2  0  1  1  0  0  1      3
4  2  0  1  1  0  0  1      3
5  2  1  1  1  0  0  1      6
6  1  1  1  1  0  0  1      5
```

Reproducible data (thanks Ananda for the First part):

```
structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L), V2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L), V3 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), V5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V7 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", 
"V7"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: +1 for figuring out the second part of the question :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I figure that for every 10 you get right and I get wrong I'll get one going my way (and note, jury still out on this one). - Actually, looks like Jury's in your favor!

Comment: The apply/all worked well when testing on small sized data frames, but I ended up switching to a merge statement with a for loop afterwards to collect indices appropriately. The computation was much faster once I switched over to real world data. Thanks to the both of you! Too bad I can't "check" both!

Comment: @adm, jnote that you can execute merges much faster with the `data.table` package, fyi.  Glad this helped.

Answer (score 0):

`apply` might be of use for the first question:

```
# Actual reproducible data!
mydf <- structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L), V2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), V3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
    V4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), V6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V7 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", 
    "V5", "V6", "V7"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
myvec <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
```

Compare each row against the "myvec" object. Use `which` to find out which row returns `TRUE`.

```
apply(mydf, 1, function(x) all(x == myvec))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
which(apply(mydf, 1, function(x) all(x == myvec)))
# [1] 5
```

Comment: The apply/all combination statement works great! The numbers should not add up, I am trying to index the second data frame based upon ordered entries in the first data frame. Sorry if the question was unclear.

Comment: Maybe `match(paste(myvec, collapse = " "), do.call(paste, mydf))` is faster? `match` should be more efficient, despite having to work with "character" now. Similarly, something like `match(do.call(paste, mydf2), do.call(paste, mydf))` for the second part. [I'm commenting it here, because it reminds me of your style in answering similar questions :-)]